# Azure VM Port for Localhost

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, port

So I'm using an Azure VM that has a public IP address, and I've opened an inbound port, let's say it's 5555.
What I'm trying to do now is to run an application on the VM that has an API via localhost, also with the port 5555. I'm calling it then with public_ip:5555/api/...

Since I was not able to connect to the application from outside, is there something missing here? Most tutorials and resources I've found just mentioned opening the port.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you enable TLS for the port?

Comment: @PranavKasetti I've allowed all Protocols, so not specifically.

Comment: are you able to ssh in? that's a good sanity check that your VM is up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Azure's IP Flow Verify utility, which will check your NSG rules to ensure traffic can reach your VM. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/network-watcher/network-watcher-ip-flow-verify-overview

If traffic is reaching your VM, check your host firewall and then your application server logs.

Comment: Thanks. It seems that it was the Windows Firewall that was blocking the port, even though the VM Port was open.